# How to record a live video and audio stream through socket to file in java using OpenCV

Tags: java, opencv, video-streaming, audio-recording, video-recording

I have capture audio and video and transmit it socket to server, where i need to record and transmit to other clients. Transmitting is working but recording, when takes place an AVI file creates with data, but not playing. Their show an error that is "Bad header AVI , missing RIFF, instead of RIFF some other data" like that.

If anyone have any idea, please help me. 
Ignore my bad grammar.

I did it in Java using OpenCV

// write the video and audio to file

ImageIO.write(frames, "bmp", vbos); //where frames contain bufferimage and vbos is objectoutputstream to fileoutputstream.

vbos.write(ret); //ret contain the audio byte array is writing to vbos,  vbos is objectoutputstream to fileoutputstream.

Comment: Please enter a example of your code to better explain your case and so that we can help you. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hai, i'm trying to directly save the incoming audio video byte array to file as AVI extension . The file is created with data but cannot play it in any of the players even in VLC.